# passing parameters through URL to action using Struts2 taglib

Tags: java, url, struts2, jstl, taglib

I was wondering if I could pass parameters through URL to a specific action.

what I would like to do, is something like this (written using jstl core):

```
<c:forEach items="${listaApprodi}" var="app">
    <tr>
            <td><a href="ApprodiServlet?app=${app.name}&lin=${requestScope.linea.name}" ><c:out value="${app.name}"></c:out></a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Of course I won't use a servlet as "destination" but I'll use an action named `OrariAction.class`.

Is it possible with Struts2 taglib?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, in a variety of ways.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Yes, of course. Even easier than with jstl. http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/tag-reference.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solution is

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<c:forEach items="${listaApprodi}" var="app">
    <tr>
       <td>
       <s:url action="your-ActionName" var="myurlvar" >
          <s:param name="app">${app.name}</s:param>
          <s:param name="lin">${requestScope.linea.name}</s:param>
       </s:url>
       <s:a href="%{myurlvar}">${app.name}</s:a>
       </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

You can also use `<s:iterator>` instead of `<c:foreach>`